Oracle: Error when compiling any stored procedure . WaitCursor.hide called without matching WaitCursor.show sql developer
I created a new Oracle RDS from an existing snapshot. But when I try to compile any existing procedure I get this error on SQL Developer :WaitCursor.hide() called without matching WaitCursor.show().
what can be the reason?

I had the same error, turns out it is not an issue with the stored procedure - rather an issue with editor.
Close tabs and restart SQL Developer.
